# Dynamic as a function argument

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica provides many functions which are capable of handling `Dynamic` as an argument.
For example, the function [FileNameSetter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileNameSetter.html) has the following variant:

```
FileNameSetter[Dynamic[name]] 
 uses the dynamically updated current value of name, with the 
 value of name being reset if a different file is chosen.
```

I wonder how one goes about defining a function pattern that takes a dynamic expression as an argument. For example, here is one attempt to wrap the dynamic variant of the function [LocatorPane](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorPane.html):

```
SinLocatorPane[Dynamic[sinvalue_]] := 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[x, (x = #; sinvalue = Sin[First[#]]) &], 
             Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

What is the correct pattern to use for a dynamic expression argument? Are there any caveats with using the dynamic argument inside the function definition?

Comment: I think the 'Custom Control Appearances' section of tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality would be relevant.  Don't forget to also read the three prerequisites mentioned at the top of that tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to write a function that updates the value of a certain variable, this is like passing a variable by reference. Standard way of achieving this in Mathematica is to use `Hold*` attributes on your function.

```
SetAttributes[SinLocatorPane, HoldFirst];
SinLocatorPane[sinvalue_] := 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[x, (x = #; sinvalue = Sin[First[#]]) &], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

Then

```
{Dynamic[sv], SinLocatorPane[sv]}
```

would work as your expected. Your code worked because Dynamic has `HoldFirst` attributed and this allowed your code to update variable `sinvalue`. Otherwise Dynamic was not really needed